# How to download and install Python Packages and Modules with Pip and those that can't be downloaded by pip?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to install module using pip to run some ML-based python programs. Can somebody share your inputs on this. I tried googling but didn't find a solution... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

PS :- I already installed pip.

Comment: please add more details - which packages weren't found with git? do you have another place with the package? (like github)?

Comment: @OphirYoktan I had issues while instaaling scikit learn and numpy

Comment: on which os?...

Comment: @OphirYoktan windows but DemongKing solution worked for me now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go to the path where python is installed for example something like this:

```
>>cd c:/users/demongking/python3/scripts
>>c:/users/demongking/python3/scripts>pip install pandas
```

you could also go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and download the wheel file (.whl) and then go to your download directory and from there you could do something like this:

```
>>c:/users/demonking/downloads>>c:/users/demongking/python3/scripts/pip 
install modulename.whl
```

Alternatively you could download setup.py file and then go to cmd and change the directory to where the setup file is downloaded and then  type

```
>>python setup.py install
```

Make sure to write full name of python version if you have multiple versions installed

Alternatively you could also do this:

```
>>py -version -m pip install modulename
```

where -version is your python version

if you want to recognize pip as a command directly by cmd you would have to change the PATH system variable

```
>>In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
>>Click the Advanced system settings link.
>>Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the 
  PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH 
  environment variable does not exist, click New.
>>In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the 
  value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining 
  windows by clicking OK.
```

Path would be where pip is contained.For example it would be something like this

> c:/users/demongking/python3/scripts/pip

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is installing packages that require compiling code, there are alternatives like:

[anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html) - a python distribution with an alternative package manager

[gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) - a collection of prebuilt windows packages for many python modules